# Understanding the relationship between C++ padding and processor

Tags: c++, performance

I was trying to understand structure padding. This is what I understood so far

Suppose I have the following struct

```
struct C
{
 int a;    //4 byte
 double d; //8 byte
 int b;    //4 byte
};
```

Now from my understanding, the compiler realizes that the highest byte size is 8 bytes because of the double. So the processor splits this into segments of 8 bytes. So we get the total size of this struct as (size of a) 4 + 4 padding + 8 (size of d) + 4 + 4 padding = 24 bytes.

So this means this struct will be 24 bytes. Now on a 64-bit machine, the processor reads 8 (word) bytes at a time. Does this mean the processor will read the struct in 3 tries? Is my understanding correct? Basically, what I am trying to understand is how padding relates to CPU performance.

Comment: Primitive pre-cache processors used to fetch one "word" at a time. Modern processorw fetches much more. The padding is more about *alignment* rather than anything else.

Comment: One important point is that you don't typically read an entire struct at a time.  You read individual elements of the struct.

Comment: Have you tried `sizeof(C)`? Is it really 24? I get only 20.

Comment: The compiler only needs to insert 4 bytes of padding between `a` and `d`. Hence, 20 bytes, not 24.

Comment: My understanding is it's 24 because that's the only way to ensure correct alignment of the `double` when defining an array of `C`. If the size was 20, then every second element will be misaligned for `C::d`.

Comment: The standard does not specify layout. So the compiler may choose 20 bytes and float the location of `d` depending on alignment of `C` instance.On even alignment, `d` would be located close to `b`, while on odd alignment it would be next to `a`. It is also possible that compiler reorders the structure and pack it in 16 bytes on 8 byte alignment boundaries, but I have not faced that one.

Comment: @Red.Wave: No. `offsetof` and `&C::d` has to work. These have to work without an actual `C` object at a given address. And `offsetof` has to be ordered in declaration order, since there are no access specifiers separating the members.

Comment: @Red.Wave *So the compiler may choose 20 bytes and float the location of d depending on alignment of C instance* No, it can not do that.  Arrays must store elements consecutively with no padding between elements.  "Float[ing] the location" is impossible because of that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is not an array; its a structure.

Comment: @Red.Wave *this is not an array; its a structure*  And that would have an effect on the result of `sizeof` how?  Please think about the implications of that...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't need to think. I once used a compiler that had different layouts for different alignments. 20 bytes of size with 4 byte alignment is simple: put the padding 4 bytes before or after the `double`  depending on the alignment of object on 8 byte boundaries. That makes reading faster for processor, while saving 4 bytes.

Comment: @Red.Wave Yeah, you do:  just how does "the compiler may choose 20 bytes and float the location" comply with [6.2.5p20](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle What's the relevant part in that doc? I can't find it. The compiler has no obligation to choose any specific layout for data members of `struct` or `class`. That is why relying on such assumptions leads to UB. Standard can never mention all approved implementations one by one. If you didn't understand the meaning of a specific phrase, you can ask. **float** is an **English verb** in my comment(not the `float` numeric type in C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you write "highest byte size is 8 bytes", I assume you meant "highest *alignment* is 8 bytes".

Such an alignment requirement (or choice*) would indeed cause the structure to be 24 bytes. This does not mean that the "processor reads the structure in 3 tries". That is not how processors work. Modern processors do not know about structures and layouts. They read  individual values from cache into registers. For an instruction like `myC.d += 1.0;` they only need to read the old `d` value, increment that, and write just that back to cache.

Similarly, the cache in a modern CPU doesn't know about structures. It works on cache lines, which have a size that's some small power of two. Since that won't divide 24, it's quite possible that a `C` instance is split over two cache lines. That would not matter much when you only use `d`, because `d` is only 8 bytes and won't be split over cache lines.

The latter does mean that it's a bit unpredictable whether `C` members share a cache line. For an array of `C` objects, the answer has to be "sometimes they do, sometimes they don't".

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of @MSalters already answers your question, I feel http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ is still a worthy read.

In essence:

Alignment depends on the size of the elements. Larger elements might have an alignment of 8, while smaller elements might have an alignment of 1, to match the alignment the compiler adds padding. When mixing different element sizes, the compiler adds more padding. In case the entire structure is accessed, a processor with a cache might have to reload more cache lines, since the structure with more padding (holes) covers more space.

Related to that, sometimes the struct members are grouped so that members which are more frequently accessed are grouped in the front. This is done in the hopes that the frequent used members might fit in the same cacheline, and less cachelines need to be loaded.

To have a play with Struct layout and see for your self compile the following example:

```
//gcc <filename> -g
#include <cstdint>

struct Unordered {
  uint8_t a;
  uint64_t b;
  uint8_t c;
};

struct Ordered {
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t c;
  uint64_t b;
};

int main() {
  Ordered o;
  Unordered u;
}
```

Then fire up gdb and have a look at the structure layout:

```
gdb <yourExecutable>
phole /o Ordered
phole /o Unordered
```

You should see output like the following (Note the different total sizes/holes):

```
(gdb) ptype /o Unordered 
/* offset      |    size */  type = struct Unordered {
/*      0      |       1 */    uint8_t a;
/* XXX  7-byte hole      */
/*      8      |       8 */    uint64_t b;
/*     16      |       1 */    uint8_t c;
/* XXX  7-byte padding   */

                               /* total size (bytes):   24 */
                             }
(gdb) ptype /o Ordered 
/* offset      |    size */  type = struct Ordered {
/*      0      |       1 */    uint8_t a;
/*      1      |       1 */    uint8_t c;
/* XXX  6-byte hole      */
/*      8      |       8 */    uint64_t b;

                               /* total size (bytes):   16 */
                             }
```